# Can you use wildcards in Solaris ipfilter?

Tags: wildcard

Solaris 10 has a very nice firewall called ipfilter.  I've been creating rules like

```
block in quick from 218.87.111.108 to any
```

to keep the Chinese hackers away but they keep coming back from other IP's.

Is there a way to specify a whole range of IP's in ipf.conf, like say 218.87.*.*?  I don't want to just try it for fear of messing something up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always hate answering my own questions but apparently this one was either too obvious or too obscure for anyone else.  Anyway, it turns out that Solaris ipfilter does indeed allow wildcards, but not using stars as one might think.  IP ranges are specified using CIDR notation, as described here http://www.aprelium.com/data/doc/2/abyssws-linux-doc-html/ipformat.html

So for example to block the entire class C and D subnets of 61.152.x.x you would specify

```
block in quick from 61.152.0.0/16 to any
```